# Android Studio toolbar title updating error with back stack from one fragment to the another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, back

i have a fragment_home that has 6 buttons and these 6 buttons have there own link(to display something like registration form ) but i have one button from these 6 buttons which is linked to another fragment and has tabbed view with view pager the title of any other fragment will update when i press back but when i entered to the button that links to the tabbed view it makes the toolbar title constant and it won't update there the application unless i exit and open again 
 for more information i have added some photos with description below 
shortly
when application Starts 
 [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqlD.png)
when i clicked users
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF6vt.png)
when i click back
[third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4sa4.png)
it updates the title correctly , when i click register own 
[fourth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpxK5.png)
it updates correctly again but now when i press back 
[last image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzShL.png)
it doesnt update the title

main navigation class

```
    package com.example.arada_tech.myapplication;



import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Navi extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Fragment fragment1;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    Tag tag;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navi);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });

         drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        Displayfragment(R.id.nav_home);
    }
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
//    @Override
//    public void onBackPressed() {
//
//        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
//        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
//            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
//
//        } else {
//            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
//                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
//            } else if (!doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
//                this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
//                Toast.makeText(this,"Please click BACK again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run() {
//                        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
//                    }
//                }, 2000);
//            }
//            else {
//                System.exit(1);
////                 super.onBackPressed();
//            }
//
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navi, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void Displayfragment(int id)
    {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new Fragment_Home();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_addbirr:
//                fragment = new Fragment_addbirr();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_adduser:
                fragment = new Fragment_addusers();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_followorders:
//                fragment = new Fragment_followorders();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_Deleteusers:
//                fragment = new Fragment_deleteusers();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_setings:
//                fragment = new Fragment_settings();
                Intent tin=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menus.class);
                startActivity(tin);
                break;
        }

        if(fragment!=null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragment1=fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_home);
                ft.replace(R.id.myframelayout,fragment);
//                ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
            ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
            ft.commit();



        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Displayfragment(item.getItemId());
         return true;
    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

}
```

my Fragment_home

```
package com.example.arada_tech.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    CardView im,in,du,ro;
    Fragment fragment=null;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getActivity().setTitle("home");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mukera,container,false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        im= (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_user);
        ro= (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_registerown);
        im.setOnClickListener(this);
        ro.setOnClickListener(this);
        in= (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_order);
        in.setOnClickListener(this);
        du= (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_deleteuser);
        du.setOnClickListener(this);

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==im){
            fragment = new Fragment_addusers();
            FragManager();

        }
        else if (v==in)
        {
//            fragment = new Fragment_followorders();
            FragManager();
        }
        else if (v==du)
        {
//            fragment = new Fragment_deleteusers();
            FragManager();
        }
        else if (v==ro)
        {
            fragment = new Fragment_registerown();
            FragManager();
        }
    }
    public  void FragManager()
    {
        if(fragment!=null)

        {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.myframelayout,fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

and my registerown fragment

```
package com.example.arada_tech.myapplication;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment_registerown extends Fragment {
    Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle("register Own");
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainslide,container,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("View"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Create"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Edit"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final ViewAdapter adapter = new ViewAdapter(((FragmentActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override

            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


            }
            @Override

            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }



            @Override

            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

        });
    }






    @Override

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


//        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

for any help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you just need to debug and check

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

method is call or not on the back event of register own fragment.you are not mentions the code line where you called  setActionBarTitle() method in the code.

Comment: on the fragment_registerown  i change the toolbar title {getActivity().setTitle("register Own");}

Comment: when you return back to start page you want change it again.

Comment: I don't  understand what you want to say. I change the title in each fragment on oncreate method....

Comment: when you return back to https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpxK5.png from  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzShL.png then check your onCreate method call other wise you can call inside onRsume method                                      
check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Comment: i try to use the below code but i cant    `@Override
    public void onResume() {
         getActivity().setTitle("Home");
        super.onResume();
    }` if you can tall me where and what to add thank you

Comment: onResume method you need to add on https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzShL.png this class it is the activity which you implement tool bar no need use getActivity()

Comment: @Override public void onResume() { super.onResume(); getActivity().setTitle("Home"); } call it like this

Comment: It's not working. I have no idea what is  problem here...  tell me what files do you want to perfectly figure out the problem

Comment: Yes. I want to change to home

Comment: Any additional help?

Comment: in the back click there is onBackPress mehod  https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal#java try this one when you click back button this method call add this method into fragment and inside method change tool bar tittle into Home if any issue  put you email here

Answer (score 0):

It works when i delete the first two lines of code in  registerown_fragment in onviewcreated method   Thank you for your help